# Implementing maximize a control to occupy the whole client area in winforms?

Tags: winforms, controls, zooming

I have 3x3 picture boxes on a form, what I want to do is when the user double click on one of the 9 picture box, I want to make the clicked picture box take the whole area, kind like a zoom effect, any idea how to implement this effect?

Comment: yes. and i also wanna switch back to it's normal size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your picturebox in form directly, you can do

```
pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```

else you need to set size and location.

```
    pictureBox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    pictureBox1.Size = this.Size;
    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```

you can select zoom sizemode to keep image quality.